# Equation of a plan through point (1, 1/2, 1/3) parallel to the plane x+y+z=0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I went about this one the same as the last two problems like it I did and came up with:

$$\langle1,1,1\rangle*\langle x-1,y-1/2,z-1/3\rangle$$
$$(x-1)+(y-1/2)+(z-1/2)=0$$
$$x+y+z = 11/8$$

But the answer is

$$6x+6y+6z = 11$$

So I'm way off aside from having an 11....

Comment: Try adding $1+\frac12+\frac13$ again.

Comment: In the second line you have $z - 1/\color{#f00}{2}$ but it must be $z - 1/\color{#f00}{3}$.